# Web frontend for Postgres database

Tags: web-apps, python, javascript, web-development, postgresql

I have a Postgres database which I need to serve to colleagues via a web-based front end.

Criteria:

- search and filter through relevant tables in the database and return records
- be able to draw onto a map to find database records within the user's region of interest, for example like https://search.asf.alaska.edu/#/ (VERY IMPORTANT)
- Add records into a table via a form request online which in turn can run python scripts to manage the backend database.

I only have knowledge of Python and PostgreSQL currently. What is the best software to use to build a web frontend?

I am aware of Django and Flask...which is the better of the two and why?

Alternatively, should I take the time to learn Javascript(?), HTML,CSS and how would this link to managing the backend in Python?